bash: /opt/ros/rolling/setup.bash: No such file or directory
I uninstall "ROS2 rolling" from my notebook these are the characteristics:
product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
vendor: Intel Corp.
physical id: 1
bus info: cpu@0
version: 6.158.10
size: 4001MHz
capacity: 4100MHz
width: 64 bits
I used this command sudo apt remove ~nros-rolling-* && sudo apt autoremove from this tutorial tutorial ros2 rolling install
After uninstall "ROS2 rolling" I forget to unsource the bash.. now every time that I use the terminal that message appears "bash: /opt/ros/rolling/setup.bash: No such file or directory"
I try to open the bash but I couldent, also I cannot create in /opt/ros/rolling/ because I don't have the permissions.
I have installed recently ROS2 Jazzy, it works normally until i cannot open the .. gedit .bashrc. How can I fixed these mistakes due to my poorly experience in Linux.
It's possible to communicate until I can fix these mistakes.
Thanks you

Try to open .bashrc with
sudo nano ~/.bashrc

Thanks you :) It works

Given that this solution solved your problem, you can mark the answer as accepted if you want :)
